# Make a Button work in an Express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to add a button to a simple webapp, however i do not know how to make it work. I am using Node,express,ejs. I have two major issues:

- What i want to make happen is that when i click the button,it should redirect me to a different page '/applist' which has a list of all my applications.
- I am trying to add an image, which doesn't show and just alt text appears.Image is in the same folder as shown. Image size is 679x1178 pixels.

There is an auto-generated app.js which of course has all required modules included.
The files below are ( index.js  , style.css,  index.ejs ) respectively.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Welcome to AJ homepage'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fjalla+One?selection.family=Fjalla+One);
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}

h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
  position: relative;
  font: ""
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    <%= title %>
  </title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="modal-body row">
  <div class="col-md-6">


    <body>
      <h1>
        <%= title %>
      </h1>
      <button class="btn" type="button">My Applications</button>
      <p>MY INFO </p>
    </body>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="../public/images/arjun.jpg.jpg" alt="My Photo" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: If you just want the button to go to a different page, then use a link like this `<a href="http://someOther URL">Clickable content here</a>` in your HTML and the browser will automatically go to a different page when the user clicks on that content.  You can put a button inside that link if you want or almost any other HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an `<a href="/my_applications">` instead of the `<button>`, you should still be able to style it as a button.  Check this answer out:
[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)
, as it shows other options, like using a `<form>`.
Also, in your express code you will need to define the route you want to serve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a button in this scenario. I suggest using an ordinary anchor link:

```
<a href="/applist" class="btn">My applications</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="/applist">` you can this anchor tag instead of button . this will be redirect to your applist page where you have define the route.